# What @EnableAutoConfiguration actually "auto-configured"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm reading [Difference Between @ComponentScan and @EnableAutoConfiguration in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-componentscan-vs-enableautoconfiguration#2-enableautoconfiguration) article. See this:

> It automatically creates and registers `beans` based on both the included jar files in the classpath and the beans defined by us.

> When we define the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in our classpath, Spring boot auto-configures `Tomcat` and `Spring MVC`.

I can understand it creates and registers `beans` based on both the included jar files. But I can't figure out what **exact things** been configured. Does it mean it will execute some beans automatically? Or something else? Is there any other example explain this?

Comment: It loads auto configuration based on the `spring.factories` (those include entires) and applies to configuration which are applicable based on the `@ConditionalOn*` rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` turns on auto configuration. Auto configuration tries to locate spring beans that should be configured for your application based on dependencies find in your classpath. Spring search for `META-INF/spring.factories` files. When it is enabled auto configuration class pointed by the property is loaded.

Consider below code snippet from spring source code:

```
@AutoConfiguration(
after = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}
) 
@ConditionalOnClass({DataSource.class, JdbcTemplate.class})
@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(DataSource.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JdbcProperties.class})
@Import({DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.class, 
         JdbcTemplateConfiguration.class, 
         NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration.class})
public class JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration {
  public JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration() {
  }
}
```

`@ComponentScan` on the other hand search for beans of your application code marked with stereotype annotations (`@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository`)